# Pipe a number into mkdir

Tags: bash, pipe, mkdir

I am trying to make a directory for every file in a directory. So far I have:

```
ls *output | sort -V | wc -l | xargs -I[] mkdir Cele_{1..[]}
```

But this results in just 1 directory named Cele_{1..1000} instead of making 1000 directories.

I am confused since typing mkdir Cele_{1..1000} creates 1000 directories, not one directory named Cele_{1..1000}.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the last command with `xargs` needs to be evaluated

```
 x=$(ls * | sort -V | wc -l  | xargs  -I[] echo Cele_{1..[]})
 eval mkdir $x
```

more error phrone approach (one liner)

```
shopt -s nullglob;fl=(*); eval mkdir Cele_{1..${#fl[@]}}; shopt -u nullglob;
```

with multiple lines

```
shopt -s nullglob
fl=(*)
eval mkdir Cele_{1..${#fl[@]}}
shopt -u nullglob
```